# Testing a class using for loop in int main

Tags: c++

In my main I have to test the class i made with a for loop but am a little stuck. I have to loop through 3 times and get user input for the ticketing system. I tried making an array and storing the user input but nothing I have tried so far has worked. Im trying to call upon the SetWorkTicket with my loop.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<iomanip>
    #include<stdexcept>
    #include<sstream>


    using namespace std;

    // start of the WorkTicket class 
    class WorkTicket{

        public:

        // defailt constructors, if the parameters are not specified the ticket will be set to 0 and the date to 1/1/2000. The rest empty strings 

        WorkTicket() : myTicketNumber(0), myClientId(""), myDay (1), myMonth (1), myYear(2000), myDescription ("") { }
        WorkTicket(int ticketNumber, string clientId, int month, int day, int year, string description);

        // mutator method that sets all attributes of the object to the parameters as long as valid. If no problems are being detected set TRUE if not then FALSE.....
        bool SetWorkTicket(int ticketNumber, string clientId, int month, int day, int year, string description);

        //  accessor method that will show all the attributes of the ticket in the console menu
        void ShowWorkTicket() const; 

        // here are the sets and gets for the attributes 

        // ticket number 

        void SetTicketNumber(int ticketNumber);
        int GetTicketNumber() const {return myTicketNumber;}

        // client id 

        void SetClientId(string clientId) {myClientId = clientId;}
        string GetClientId() const { return myClientId;}

        // date by day 

        void SetDay(int day);
        int GetDay() const { return myDay; }

        // date by month

        void SetMonth(int month);
        int GetMonth() const { return myMonth; } 

        // date by year 

        void SetYear(int year);
        int GetYear() const { return myYear; }

        // description 

        void SetDescription(string description) { myDescription = description; }  
        string GetDescription() const { return myDescription; }


        private: 

        int myTicketNumber; 
        string myClientId; 
        int myDay; 
        int myMonth;
        int myYear; 
        string myDescription; 

    };



    // the work ticket constructor definition 
    WorkTicket::WorkTicket(int ticketNumber, string clientId, int month, int day, int year, string description)
    {

        SetTicketNumber(ticketNumber);
        SetClientId(clientId);
        SetMonth(month);
        SetDay(day);
        SetYear(year);
        SetDescription(description);
    }

    // set work ticket 
    bool WorkTicket::SetWorkTicket(int ticketNumber, string clientId, int month, int day, int year, string description)
    {
         const int MAX_DAY = 31; // setting max day to 31
         const int MAX_MONTH = 12; // max month to 12 
         const int MIN_YEAR = 2000; // the min year 2000 as specified 
         const int MAX_YEAR = 2099; // max year 2099 as speciified 
         bool valid = true; 
        //  setting the limits 
         if(ticketNumber < 0 || month < 1 || month > MAX_MONTH ||
            day < 1 || day > MAX_DAY ||
            year < MIN_YEAR || year > MAX_YEAR)
            valid = false;

         else if (clientId.length() < 1 || description.length() < 1)
            valid = false;
         else 
         {    
            myTicketNumber = ticketNumber;
            myClientId = clientId;
            myDay = day;
            myMonth = month;
            myYear = year;
            myDescription = description;
         }

         return valid;
    }

    // this is to show the work ticket, it will show everything in the console..
    void WorkTicket::ShowWorkTicket() const
    {
         cout << "\nWork Ticket Number: " << myTicketNumber
              << "\nClient ID:     " << myClientId
              << "\nDate:   " << setw(2) << setfill('0') << myMonth
              << "/" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << myDay
              << "/" << myYear
              << "\nIssue:         " << myDescription << endl;
    }

    void WorkTicket::SetTicketNumber(int ticketNumber)
    {
            if(ticketNumber > 0)
            {
                myTicketNumber = ticketNumber;
            }
            else
            {
                throw invalid_argument("Try Again.");
            }
    }

    // WorkTicket::SetDay definition
    void WorkTicket::SetDay(int day)
    {
            const int MIN_VALID = 1;
            const int MAX_VALID = 31;
            if(day >= MIN_VALID && day <= MAX_VALID)
            {
                myDay = day;
            }
            else
            {
                throw invalid_argument("Try Again.");
            }
    }

    // WorkTicket::SetMonth definition
    void WorkTicket::SetMonth(int month)
    {
            const int MIN_VALID = 1;
            const int MAX_VALID = 12;
            if(month >= MIN_VALID && month <= MAX_VALID)
            {
                myMonth = month;
            }
            else
            {
                throw invalid_argument("Try Again.");
            }
    }

    // WorkTicket::SetYear definition
    void WorkTicket::SetYear(int year)
    {
            const int MIN_VALID = 2000;
            const int MAX_VALID = 2099;
            if(year >= MIN_VALID && year <= MAX_VALID)
            {
                myYear = year;
            }
            else
            {
                throw invalid_argument("Try Again.");
            }
    }

    int main()
    {   
        const int NUMBER_OF_TICKETS = 3;  
        WorkTicket tickets[NUMBER_OF_TICKETS]; 

        int ticketNumber;
        string clientId; 
        int day;
        int month;
        int year; 
        string description; 

        for (int i = 0; i <NUMBER_OF_TICKETS; i++)  
        {
            cout << "\WorkTicket [" << i << "]: " << endl; 

            cout << "Enter the ticket number: " << endl; 
            cout << "Enter the client ID: " << endl; 
            getline(cin, clientId);
            day = SetDay("Enter a day number: ");  

        }
    }
```

Comment: There seems to be a lot of code unrleated to your problem. Please try to create a [mcve] and post it.

Comment: Why is your `SetDay` function being passed a string when it takes an integer?

Comment: Where do you use that `WorkTicket` array in `main` after you declared it?  You have to actually do something with the array `tickets` at some point, but you failed to do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest of your code works correctly and you only have problems in the main:

There are a few issues as commented by others in your code in main:

1) You declared `WorkTicket tickets[NUMBER_OF_TICKETS];` but have not used it anywhere.

2) The variable `tickets` is an array and therefore in the for loop `tickets[i]` is of type `WorkTicket`.

3) `SetDay` is a member function of `WorkTicket` and takes `int` as argument.

In light of these, following changes made:

```
for (int i = 0; i <NUMBER_OF_TICKETS; i++)  
{
    cout << "\WorkTicket [" << i << "]: " << endl; 

    cout << "Enter the ticket number: " << endl; 
    cout << "Enter the client ID: " << endl; 
    getline(cin, clientId);
    cout<<"Enter a day number:";
    int day;
    cin>>day;
    tickets[i].SetDay(day);  //day is int and tickets[i] is of WorkTicket

}
```

Hope this helps to understand the `main` part better.

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful, otherwise a [cargo cult programmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) is in the making.

Answer (score 0):

Gather the input and then construct a WorkTicket.  Push the tickets into a vector. In the code yet to be written, the newly create WorkTickets can be tested for correctness.

Make sure to include vector at the top of the file.

```
int main()
{   
    const int NUMBER_OF_TICKETS = 3;  

    int ticketNumber;
    string clientId; 
    int day;
    int month;
    int year; 
    string description; 
    std::vector<WorkTicket> tickets;

    for (int i = 0; i <NUMBER_OF_TICKETS; i++)  
    {
        cout << "WorkTicket [" << i << "]: " << endl; 

        cout << "Enter the ticket number: " << endl; 
        cin>> ticketNumber;
        cout << "Enter the client ID: " << endl; 
        cin >> clientId;
        cout << "Enter a day number: " << endl; 
        cin >>  day;
        cout << "Enter a month number: " << endl; 
        cin>> month;
        cout << "Enter a year number: " << endl; 
        cin>> year;
        cout << "Enter a description : " << endl; 
        cin >> description;
        try {
           tickets.push_back({ticketNumber, clientId, month, day, year, description});
        } 
        catch(std::exception e)
        {
           std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```